# LAST_INSERT_ID takes too long to process

Tags: mysql

I ran into an issue with LAST_INSERT_ID() ,  it exams all rows for some reason and takes a lot time to process
how to manage that ?

I haven't tried anything yet , what shows in slow query log is :

```
# User@Host: ****[****] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 3748779  Schema: ****  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.000681  Lock_time: 0.000038  Rows_sent: 1557  Rows_examined: 1557
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 15635
use ****;
SET timestamp=1697933512;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM p_queue;
```

Comment: Possibly should set the particular query engine into the query also, but interestingly, if it examined all of them in operational sort order of insert to find the last, it would also be the last with the soonest modification stamp, or perhaps sorted them into am order first then determined last, or worse, compared them with each to other completely. It may been better to sort them yourself to a temp table first then taken the last or examined it.

Answer (score 3):

You are querying the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for every row of your table `p_queue`.

This is unnecessary, because the value returned by `LAST_INSERT_ID()` won't change until you INSERT a row into a table with an auto-increment primary key.

You should just query one row to get the result of an invariant expression.

You can do this in MySQL in either of the following ways:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM dual;
```

`dual` is a fake table that is guaranteed to have one row and no columns. It takes no overhead to query from `dual` as it does to query from a real table. In MySQL, these two queries are equivalent. The `dual` table is supported for compatibility with Oracle.

Comment: And it doesn't have to actually commit  the insert involving auto_increment for the `last_insert_id` to increase in value. A rollback right after the insert does not roll back the `last_insert_id` value, which saves space for the sequence-generating table. Learnt this from your book in chapter 9. Thanks.

Comment: you mean I should just use SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); without putting "from p_queue " ?

Comment: Right, because using `from p_queue` in this case just returns the same value 1500 times, and the extra overhead of reading the table for no purpose.

Comment: and that is 100% safe ?

Comment: Safe from what? What are you concerned will happen?

Comment: @morgitmrdasdas I think you are misunderstanding how it works. Adding `FROM p_queue` does not switch the context to the `p_queue` table, it just makes it return as many rows of the same `LAST_INSERT_ID()` return value as there are rows in the `p_queue` table. The value returned by `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is maintained on a [_per-connection basis_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id:~:text=per%2Dconnection%20basis), not per-table per-connection. Here's an example which should help - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ur9p3dAp).